# How can I remount a disk partion and clear its data?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount

Long ago, I had to reinstall Ubuntu on my Laptop. Unfortunately my disk got split into 2 partitions. Now I want to remount the 2nd partition. However I am not sure what steps to take.

Do I need to clear the 2nd partition first? (no useful data there)

Which tools should I use? (e.g. Gparted)

Any other good advice?

[image: Gparted: Showing my Disk.]

**I'd like to clear sda4 and remount it to sda5**

Comment: You probably don't mean to remount. Do you want to delete sda4 and grow sda5 so that it incorporates the free space where sda4 used to be?

Comment: I would backup your data from your /media/fe... (twice), boot a live system (eg. install media) and use that to delete the /media/fe... partition, then grow the other one to use the space. Reboot and all should be good.  (at worst a 1% chance of a grub issue, but extremely unlikely & easily fixed)

Answer (score 0):

[guiverc's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146809/how-can-i-remount-a-disk-partion-and-clear-its-data#comment1904157_1146809) was a good help. I used the following steps:

1. delete the partition with Gparted
2. reinstall GRUB
3. boot a live system | boot from USB stick with Ubuntu ISO
4. use Gparted to resize the disk space
5. reboot